# SQLAlchemy group_by return object with aggregated values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Let's consider that we have such schema:

```
class Owner(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'owners'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(30), nullable=False)

    shares = db.relationship('Share', secondary=lambda: shares_owners, lazy="dynamic")

class Share(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'shares'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    apartment = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    owners = db.relationship('Owner', secondary=lambda: shares_owners, lazy="dynamic")

shares_owners = db.Table('shares_owners',
    db.Column('share_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('shares.id')),
    db.Column('owner_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('owners.id'))
)
```

Filtering shares owned by an owner is piece of cake:

```
Share.query.join(shares_owners, Owner, User).filter(User.id == 1).all()
```

You can easily group and sum values with `func.sum` but when you do that sqlalchemy returns only the summed field.

Is there a way to force it to return `Share` object (or something based on `Share`) with summed up value?

Ideally will be to call `.summed()` method instead of `.one()`, `.first()` or `.all()` which will return some `Share` like object with summed values.

Comment: What do you expect inside this "Share like object". If you sum values from 5 `Share` objects, what do you expect inside `id` or `apartment` field? In general: can you provide a small example of what do you have inside DB and what do you expect to be returned by calling method you want?

Comment: Same stuff as in Share object, so yes, the sum of the values, ids and apartment and others can be None.

The idea is that if some owner owns 1000 shares he can see them as one and treat them as one.

Comment: My second idea is to create custom collection_class that will behave like ordinary list but with additional methods to sum up the `.value`

Comment: It's still not clear, WHAT do you want to achieve. If the only not None field is sum of values, use this value to display it to user (no need to wrap it). If you want to update or delete all user's shares, use [`update()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update) or [`delete()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.delete). Like `Share.query.join(shares_owners, Owner, User).filter(User.id == 1).delete()`. It's less ORMy, but gives you much better performance than separate query for each instance.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to have less as possible logic in the web templates.

I have an template that displays list of shares with some form for each one and if owner have more than one `Share` i just want to aggregate them and show one form.

So i figured out that if i will mimic the behavior of `Share` with some other object i could display it without any additional logic in templates (the logic of summing/counting/whatever will be held within this `Share`-like class.

Comment: Okey, now I see your point. I don't know details of your form, but you will still need to implement view and form for it. Even if you reuse template, it's quite weird to use same form for a single item and all items at once (they are completely different by their nature). I would still write everything explicitly instead of doing that.

Comment: You're right... I've redesigned stuff in the mean time. Thanks for the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging :)